# Can't install libmysqlclient-dev package when building dockerfile with ubuntu

Tags: mysql, docker, apt-get

I have the following content on my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip libmysqlclient-dev
```

And I got this output:

```
Step 4 : RUN apt-get install -y python-pip libmysqlclient-dev
 ---> Running in 2fb54b3107d4
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package libmysqlclient-dev 
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python-pip libmysqlclient-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

The weird thing is that if I run the same thing using `docker run` over the same image, the command works fine:

```
$ docker run -it --rm ubuntu bash
root@5f4d0083bd31:/# apt-get update && apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Sources [1103 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Sources [5179 B]                                                                                        
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Sources [9802 kB]                                                                                         
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1558 kB]                                                                                      
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [14.1 kB]                                                                                
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [9827 kB]                                                                                  
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Sources [261 kB]                                                                                     
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Sources [1872 B]                                                                               
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Sources [137 kB]                                                                                 
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [548 kB]                                                                              
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [11.7 kB]                                                                       
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [459 kB]                                                                          
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Sources [60.7 kB]                                                                                   
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Sources [1872 B]                                                                              
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Sources [15.8 kB]                                                                               
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [225 kB]                                                                             
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [11.7 kB]                                                                      
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [76.9 kB]                                                                        
Fetched 24.6 MB in 1min 26s (284 kB/s)                                                                                                                           
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libmysqlclient20 linux-libc-dev manpages manpages-dev mysql-common zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc man-browser
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient20 linux-libc-dev manpages manpages-dev mysql-common zlib1g-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6
1 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 35.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

What could be wrong when using Dockerfile?

Thanks

Comment: Could this be a caching issue? Have you tried building it with the `-no-cache` option?

Comment: I have no problems building an image from the above docker file?

Comment: @Cyclone thanks, but adding that option doesn't change aything

Comment: Weird. This works well for me on debbian:jessie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Debian releases older or equal 8, this package is named: `libmysqlclient-dev`

For Debian releases newer than 8, this package is named: `default-libmysqlclient-dev`

Answer (score 10):

Use of `default-libmysqlclient-dev` in  Dockerfile

instead of `libmysqlclient-dev` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this problem with a debian container. What fixed it was installing each package with separate commands. So instead of

`RUN apt-get install -y python-pip libmysqlclient-dev`

do

`RUN apt-get install -y python-pip`

`RUN apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev`

Answer (score 5):

For Alpine you can use `mariadb-dev` instead of `default-libmysqlclient-dev`

```
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:3.9
RUN apk-install mariadb-dev mariadb-client
```

[Connecting to MySQL / MariaDB](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-9-installing-popular-packages-on-alpine)

---

mariadb-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev

Answer (score 1):

If you strictly need mysql development libraries in alpine, you can also use

```
RUN APK add mysql-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `libmariadb-dev`, that suits for me in Debian 12