# Unable to locate package libmysqlclient-dev

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2, libmysql

ruby 2.6.3
Ubuntu 16.04
Unable to locate package libmysqlclient-dev

description:
Fetching mysql2 0.5.2
Installing mysql2 0.5.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

To solve this I ran following.

gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'

Then got the following error.
mysql client is missing. You may need to 'apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev'

now I am stuck and found no solution working. tried google and all other option but no suggestion is working for me.
Unable to locate package libmysqlclient-dev

Comment: did you try "sudo apt-update && sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev" ?

Comment: yes I did. I tried "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
"
but of no use.

Comment: @UmairLiaquat , try using ```sudo apt-get install mysql-server``` followed by ```sudo mysql_secure_installation``` and then follow the instructions, later on access mysql using ```mysql -u root -p followed by password```

Comment: @AmanRelan Unable to locate package mysql-server

Comment: Try [`default-libmysqlclient-dev`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55917381/3784008), and if that does not work then [reset your apt sources](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/308872) and try again with both package names.

Comment: @UmairLiaquat do this first then ```sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade``` and then do ```sudo apt-get install mysql-server``` followed by ```sudo mysql_secure_installation```

Answer (score 2):

To give you proper answer as I found that all comments are to the point, but I wanted to check if really such issue exists. So I spin up new ubuntu server 16.04 and used following commands to installd mysql gem. I used rvm to install ruby

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rvm
```

Now relogin to terminal to rvm command can start with its environment

```
rvm install ruby 2.6.3
```

Now I used `ruby -version` to check I am using same version as you were so got response `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]` Now I used following command to install gem. If it succeed then rails will be also installed.

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

But I am getting same error as yours, now let us solve it as it is saying us how to solve error. This error is already giving me information what should I do. It told me to install following package

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

And now I tried again and it worked. Hope it will resolve your issue.  If you still have issue, than you can try by removing mysql packages you install and reinstall using these commands.